# How to map the default document in iis residing inner folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

[image]

**How can I map the default document file from Dir2 folder. There I have a index.html file. While I configure as**

[image]

**the js file and css files are not working with this index.html page. How can I solve this issue?**

Comment: If the page is loading but js and css files not, the problem is not with setting the default page but with files paths. Please add some of them.

Comment: i dont get it. "Please add some of them"- means?

Comment: Can I add the subitems to the DefaultDocuent list?

Comment: File paths that aren't working

Comment: then its not possible for me?

Comment: but when I browse with the file inside Dir2 its working fine.

Comment: is this functionality not working in iis?

Comment: cn u provide me sample codes

Comment: you said the page is working but your problem is tha js files and css are not loading. I'm a little confused about that.

Comment: js and css are working when I browse as Ap1/Dir1/Dir2/index.html. But its not working when I browse as Ap1/index.html

Comment: page can view on ap1/index.html but js and css are not working with it.

Comment: You could try using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/css/yourname.css")%>/>` for getting the correct path on the aspx

Comment: my page is an html page. not aspx page. In this situation is it possible for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't sound like it has anything to do with IIS or default documents and everything to do with how you included your references to your style and script files in your HTML pages. You'll need to make sure the URLs are correct in each page. If you try to browse to the JS or CSS file using the URLs you specified in Ap1/index.html, what happens? If you get a 404 then your src or href attributes are incorrect in *that* file.

Based on your comments, if you're looking to use the exact same page at different levels of your application, you'll need to convert the paths to your JavaScript and CSS files to absolute paths. An absolute path starts with a forward slash "/" and progresses from the root of your site hierarchy until it reaches your file. For example, if you had your script files at a folder just below the root level you'd do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/myscript.js"></javascript>
```

Likewise for a style in a folder below the root level you'd do the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/mystyle.css" />
```

The client browser should then be able to find your files no matter where in your site hierarchy you've placed your index.html.

Comment: my urls are correct in each page. Also it worked correctly when I browse with the URL (Ap1/Dir1/Dir2/index.html). But styles are not getting when I put the url as (Ap1/index.html). Also its an HTML pahe. Can I put ResolveClientUrl in html page?

Comment: my page is an html page. not aspx page. In this situation is it possible for me?

Comment: If your styles are not working when you browse to Ap1/index.html then your hrefs are incorrect on THAT page. If I understand you correctly, you are trying to use a page at Ap1/Dir1/Dir2/index.html and also wanting to use it at Ap1/index.html. This will require that you use *absolute* paths to your scripts and styles. No you cannot use server-side scripting on an html page.

Comment: how can I use absolute paths to scripts and styles. Can you give me some suggestions...